# Find all points satisfying $x^3+y^3+1=0$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ and conclude that there is a rational point over $\mathbb{F}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find all points satisfying $x^3+y^3+1=0$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ and conclude that there is a rational point over $\mathbb{F}_4$.

**Answer:**

The field $\mathbb{F}_2$ contains the elements $\{\bar 0, \bar 1 \}$.

Then $(x,y)=(\bar 0, \bar 0), \ (\bar 0 , \bar 1 ) , \ (\bar 1, \bar 0) \ or \ (\bar 1, \bar 1)$.

Cleraly, $ \ (\bar 0, \bar 1) \ $ and  $(\bar 1, \bar 0) \ $ satisfy the equation $x^3+y^3+1=0$.

Thus first part is clear.

**How to answer the next part?**

Comment: The formulation of the question is a bit strange. Any solutions in $\Bbb{F}_2$ are automatically also solutions in $\Bbb{F}_4$. But, you do get more solution in the bigger field. Hint: $x^3=1$ for all $x\in\Bbb{F}_4\setminus\Bbb{F}_2$.

Comment: the question says, we have to find $ rational \ \ point $ on $ \ \mathbb{F}_4 \ $

Comment: Is my  1st part correct?

Comment: "Rational over $\Bbb{F}_4$" is standard shorthand for a solution $(x,y)$ such that **both** $x$ and $y$ are elements of the field $\Bbb{F}_4$. The parlance is used also for more variables (and systems of equations). I'm sure this is explained in your book/lecture notes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a genus $1$ curve, so there is $\alpha\in\Bbb C$ with the property that $|\alpha|=2$ and the number of projective points over $\Bbb F_{2^n}$ is
$$1+2^n-\alpha^n-\overline\alpha^n.$$
There are three points on the curve in the projective plane over $\Bbb F_2$,
so we have $\alpha=\pm i\sqrt2$. Then over $\Bbb F_4$ there are
$$1+4+2+2=9$$
points. At most three lie on the "line ant infinity" and three
already are defined over $\Bbb F_2$, so at least three are affine
points defined over $\Bbb F_4$ but not over $\Bbb F_2$.